# Multiple selection with multiple sections in UItableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If I select the first indexPath of first section , all the first indexPath of different sections gets selected like the image. How to rectify it?

[image]

```
if ([arraySelectedValue‌​s containsObject:array‌​StateNames[indexPath.‌​row]]) { 
    cell.imageCheck.imag‌​e =[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"]‌​; 
} else { 
    cell.imageCheck.imag‌​e =[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck‌​"];
}
```

Comment: Give the related code

Comment: Thats because of `dequeueReusableCell`, you need to update value in each cell as well keep track of your selected indexPath and mark as selected/normal accordingly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I have 20 sections like this ..is there any way to get through this @DipenPanchasara

Comment: Store selected indexPath in a MutableArray, check it in `willDisplayCell` and make decision whether to show selected or not.

Comment: show the `cellForRowAtIndexPa‌​th` selecting cells code.

Comment: if ([arraySelectedValues containsObject:arrayStateNames[indexPath.row]]) {
               
              
                cell.imageCheck.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];
                
                
            }
            else
            {
                cell.imageCheck.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"];
                
            }

Comment: Try reloading **particular row of particular section**...Something like this, `        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[your selected NSIndexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

Comment: Show the code - everyone is guessing!

Comment: this is completely problem of reusing. you need to set uncheck image in cellForRowAtIndexPath. after that check and change image.

Comment: Hey, could you please edit your question by adding the entire code of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method ? Could you also add what your do when the selection state of a cell change ?

Comment: I got it by storing indexpath in an array ..thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following.

```
if ([arraySelectedValue‌​s containsObject:indexPath])
{
    cell.imageCheck.imag‌​e =[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"]‌​;
}
else
{
    cell.imageCheck.imag‌​e =[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck‌​"];

}
```

and in didSelectRow method write the below code

```
if ([arraySelectedValues containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [arraySelectedValues removeObject:indexPath];
}
else
{
    [arraySelectedValues addObject:indexPath];

}
```

and reload the section or row

Answer (score 0):

For this you need create a global  arr to hold selected indexPath in your h file

```
NSMutable *arrSelectedIndex;
```

in your didSelectItemAtIndexPath you need to write below code.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self selectDeselectIndexpath:indexPath];
    [collectionView reloadData];

}


// this method is used to toggle between selection and deselection 
-(void) selectDeselectIndexpath : (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{

    for (int i=0; i < arrSelectedIndex.count; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *index = [arrSelectedIndex objectAtIndex:i];
        if (index.row == indexPath.row && index.section == indexPath.section) {
            [arrSelectedIndex removeObject:index];
            return ;
        }
    }
    [arrSelectedIndex addObject:indexPath];

}
// this method is used to select any indexPath
-(void) selectIndexpath : (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{

    for (int i=0; i < arrSelectedIndex.count; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *index = [arrSelectedIndex objectAtIndex:i];
        if (index.row == indexPath.row && index.section == indexPath.section) {
            return ; // This means indexPath already selected
        }
    }
    [arrSelectedIndex addObject:indexPath];
}
    // this method is used to deselect any indexPath
-(void) deselectIndexpath : (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{

    for (int i=0; i < arrSelectedIndex.count; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *index = [arrSelectedIndex objectAtIndex:i];
        if (index.row == indexPath.row && index.section == indexPath.section) {
            [arrSelectedIndex removeObject:index];
            return ; // Indexpath found and remove from array
        }
    }
    // Reaching over here means this indexpath not selected;
}
```

You can use any the above method as per you need.